# Flutter iOS Email Text Field Content Type

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm implementing a login screen in Flutter and I cannot set the Content-Type on an email text field. On an iOS app, the content type needs to be set in order for email addresses suggestions to display while editing.

Am I missing something or is this not yet supported?

```
  TextFormField(
    maxLines: 1,
    keyboardAppearance: Brightness.light,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
    focusNode: _emailFocus,
    autofocus: true,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Email',
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.mail,
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
    ),
    validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? "Email can't be empty" : null,
    onSaved: (value) => _email = value.trim(),
    onFieldSubmitted: (term) => _fieldFocusChange(context, _emailFocus, _passwordFocus),
  )
```

There is an option for this in Xcode:
[image: xcode screen shot]

Comment: Would you mind accepting an answer, if it resolved your issue?

Answer (score 4):

There is a keyboardType

```
new TextFormField
 (
   keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress
   ...
)
```

Comment: This is not the same thing; It does not show suggested email addresses on the QuickType bar like setting the text input trait does

Answer (score 4):

Try setting both `autofillHints` and `keyboardType`

```dart
TextFormField(
  autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.email],
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  ...
)
```

See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/autofillHints.html for more details.